# Zooming in Google Chrome using the mouse wheel?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, mouse, zoom

On Windows and, if I'm not mistaken, on Linux, it's possible to zoom in and out in Google Chrome using the mouse wheel. However, this doesn't seem to be working on Mac OS X.

Does anybody know if this feature can be enabled? Or is there any alternative solution (plugin, script, etc.)?

Answer (score 19):

You can pinch to zoom, which will simulate <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd><kbd>+</kbd>
and <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd><kbd>-</kbd>

You can also try [the extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/zoomwheel/kdfgigbjonaniokmpfflpflkhahhbaej/details?utm_source=chrome-ntp-icon), which was mentioned by in [Danijel's answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/103980/7833).

Otherwise, you can hold down <kbd>Control ^</kbd> and the *screen* will zoom in and out. It ends up looking like this though (which I don't think you want):

[image]

Comment: The extension mentioned does not work on recent Macs.

Comment: Hold down control in some OS should work only if the option [Use scroll gesture with modifier keys to zoom](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH21498?locale=en_US) is flagged

Comment: Pinch is a good alternative solution, but it doesn't work on a mouse with an actual physical scroll wheel.  :(

Answer (score 9):

Using this [extension from taharactrl](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/zoom-with-control%2Bmousewh/hgjighmjoknclbcfamhaibphjpbgjgmk?hl=en-US) I was able to zoom with ctrl+mouse wheel on all websites.

OSX El Capitan + Chrome 47

Note : after installing the extension, for it to work on existing opened tabs you have to reload them.

Comment: I can confirm this works under OSX El Capitan & Chrome 54 (Nov 2016).

Comment: doesn't work on macOs Mojave

Comment: Confirm it works on Big Sur (but only on new tabs after installing it)

Comment: Sorry.. but yet another feature i see as pretty basic, missing from macos..

Answer (score 8):

In yosemite, you can activate it at the system level. For example:

`Preferences` > `Accessibility` > `Zoom` > `Use scroll gesture with keys to zoom`

Select `^ control`

Then use `control` and the mouse scroll to zoom.

(Alternatively, tough that's not what's asked, in chrome, you can pinch to zoom by default)

Comment: The problem with this approach is that it actually zooms the screen. It does not simply change the font size and spacing. (use em's people)

Comment: @DRaehal have you figured out a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 3):

Use Command and the + button to zoom in!

Comment: True, but the question was about how to do it with the mouse scroll wheel, presumably so you don't have to take your hand off the mouse.

Answer (score 2):

<del>There's a Google Chrome [extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/zoomwheel/kdfgigbjonaniokmpfflpflkhahhbaej/details?utm_source=chrome-ntp-icon) you can use to do this.</del>
**Note:** This no longer works!

---

Hold down <kbd>Control</kbd> as you scroll and it will zoom in/out.
**Note:** Use this instead!

Comment: that does not work for me, i always used ctrl+mousewheel also on windows but on mac its not working for me

Comment: -1 On OS X Yosemite: Tried extension. It said to hold right mouse button and scroll to zoom - that worked on 1 page but inconsistently, and not at all on 9 other pages I tried (including this one). Also, <kbd>Control</kbd> scroll and <kbd>command</kbd> scroll don't work by default - that's what the question is.

Comment: Indeed the extension does not work on OS X Mavericks either.

Comment: Does not work in Chrome 69 on MacOS 10.13

Answer (score 1):

For Macs, you can use [BetterTouchTool](https://folivora.ai/) (free trial for 45 days, then paid). You can assign the action <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>Scroll Up</kbd> to emit the keyboard shortcut <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>+</kbd>, and similar for scrolling down.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution for Google Chrome:**

- Zoom out: <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd>
- Zoom in: <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>¨</kbd> (Actually does not work when the cursor is actively blinking in a text field)
- Reset zoom: <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>=</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

There is no + button for MacBooks! Only possible to write + if you hold down shift and 3 together. It's impossible to zoom out currently without using a proper USB/BT keyboard. And every site or forum I found so far suggested the cmd + or cmd - option which is not working. Only the cmd - because there is a dedicated - button. But nothing for +

Comment: If there's no `+` on your keyboard, how are you using it in your answer? When Cmd + is mentioned, what is actually implied is Cmd =. You do not need to shift +. This of course is very dependant on which country keyboard you are using. As it stands your answer does not really satisfy the requirements of an answer to the standard we expect here. Please see if you can improve it. Also please have a read of https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: I explained it clearly. In order for me to write the plus character, I need to press and hold SHIFT and the "3" key at once. Keyboard layout is Hungarian QWERTZ. This is just the first thing that bugs my mind since I moved to macOS. No dedicated "delete" button, no dedicated "save as" feature, just to mention a few. I'm not sure what Apple developers are thinking before they remove basic features that every normal(non-Apple) device has...

Comment: Now it's clear that your issues are to do with the specific keyboard, it sounds like you may want to open a question of your own to help address that. I'm sure that there are other Hungarian macOS users here who'd be happy to help. As it stands though, your answer is not relevant to the original question, which is asking re. mouse zooming in Chrome. As to your other points, these have long been part of the design and would stray very much into 'why does Apple do this?' territory, and questions re. Apple's design choices are off-topic here.

Comment: Well, since I had no way of commenting, this was the only way to ask for clarification from others. I don't feel like starting a whole new thread on a question that was already asked... On other forums this is greatly discouraged. Seems like it's encouraged here instead. Strange.